# Optimization problem -building a rectangular aquarium

Tags: calculus, optimization

We need to build a rectangular aquarium with a volume of 12 cubic feet. The material for the bottom costs 6 dollars per sq foot, and the sides cost 2 dollars per square foot; it has no top. find the dimensions of the least expensive aquarium we can build.

[image: Optimization problem - aquarium]

How do they get to $8=l^3$ from $6l-\frac{48}{8/l^2}$=0 ?

Comment: Please don’t include critical parts of your question as an image. It is neither searchable nor accessible to those using a screen reader.

Comment: This was, of course, an exercise in partial derivatives of multivariable functions, but in practice, you could’ve simplified the problem after deriving $C(l,w)$. Observe that this function is symmetric in its arguments, so you’re going to end up with $l=w$ and can reduce this to a single-.variable problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$6l - \frac{48}{(8/l^2)^2}=0$

$6l - \frac{48}{64/l^4}=0$

$6l - \frac{48l^4}{64}=0$

$24l - 3l^4=0$

$l=0 $ or $l^3=8$